# Duplicates mails in Lotus Notes 8.5 after replication

Tags: lotus-notes

I had the very bad idea to copy and paste some missing mails from a message database to a second one. After a replication I get about a thousand of duplicates !
How could I remove them easily ? I can't do it manualy of course.
I searched around the WEB and didn't find nothing about dulicates mails deleting tool, it seems to be only calendar, tasks ans contacts duplicates removing tools available.

Tnak you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

All the pasted documents will have a Created and Modified timestamp matching when you pasted the documents. You can therefore create a view sorted by Creation Date and from that view much easier identify the pasted documents.

You can create the view by using Create - View in the mail database, choose to copy style from e.g. All Documents, and then use Save and Customize. This will open the view in design mode and you can then add a column sorted on Creation Date (or change an existing column to sort on Creation Date).

Comment: Tank you for your quick responses !

Comment: I'll try this soon !

Comment: did you get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off issue, manual is going to be easiest by far I'm afraid. Unfortunately, most Notes installations do not include much in the way of automation help.

Development for Notes is a rather specialist subject so resources and skills are few and far between.

---

To do it manually:

Change the sorting on the view containing the mails so that they all appear together - probably by sorting on "Subject" or maybe "Who". Then, holding down the shift key, use the arrow keys to select all of the duplicate mails. You can then delete them.

I note that in Notes 6.5 the default Inbox doesn't allow sorting on Subject for some reason.

You could also create your own View - I have two additional views that I always create - "All By Date" and "All By Person" which include ALL mails (sent as well as received, calendar & email). Unfortunately, I can't give you a simple formula here to create a view due to the nature of the View designer in Notes but it isn't too hard - you may need to look up the help though as your admins may not have included the development help files.